# Python3 function with pandas dataframe input runs slower then 1st time and faster the 2nd time

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, function, pandas

I built 2 functions major_check_with_dataframe and major_check_with_list, and I wanted to see which one runs faster. I'm puzzled by their run time.

```
import numpy as np
DTYPE_FLOAT = np.float
import anapyfunc.major
import pandas as pd
from testpython.timer import timer

# wrapper function
def major_check(**kwargs):
    #return major_check_with_list(**kwargs)
    return major_check_with_dataframe(**kwargs)

# functions to be timed
def major_check_with_dataframe(df, s_major_single_hi_percent, s_major_single_lo_percent):
    ...

def major_check_with_list(source_list, s_major_single_hi_percent, s_major_single_lo_percent):
    ...

# main function starts here
t = timer.Timer(verbose = True, run = False)
t.set_name(name = 'major check timer')

a = np.random.choice(101, 2500)
b = np.random.choice(101, 2500)
c = np.random.choice(101, 2500)

s_major_single_hi_percent = 70 
s_major_single_lo_percent = 10

dd = {'a' : a, 'b' : b , 'c' : c}
df = pd.DataFrame(dd)

# axis 0 = tick
# axis 1 = input arrays

t.set_name(name = 'major_check_with_dataframe')
t.start()
ret1 = anapyfunc.major.major_check_with_dataframe(
                                  df = df, 
                                  s_major_single_hi_percent = s_major_single_hi_percent,
                                  s_major_single_lo_percent = s_major_single_lo_percent,
                                 )
t.stop_reset()

t.set_name(name = 'major_check_with_list')
t.start()
ret2 = anapyfunc.major.major_check_with_list(
                                source_list = [a, b, c,],
                                  s_major_single_hi_percent = s_major_single_hi_percent,
                                  s_major_single_lo_percent = s_major_single_lo_percent,
                                )
t.stop_reset()


t.set_name(name = 'major_check')
t.start()
ret3 = anapyfunc.major.major_check(
                                  #source_list = [a, b, c,],
                                  df = df, 
                                  s_major_single_hi_percent = s_major_single_hi_percent,
                                  s_major_single_lo_percent = s_major_single_lo_percent,
                                 )
t.stop_reset()
```

Output when major_check calls major_check_with_dataframe

```
major_check_with_dataframe elapsed time: 94.261000 ms
major_check_with_list elapsed time: 2.316000 ms
major_check elapsed time: 3.055000 ms
```

Output when major_check calls major_check_with_list

```
major_check_with_dataframe elapsed time: 95.042000 ms
major_check_with_list elapsed time: 2.240000 ms
major_check elapsed time: 2.240000 ms
```

I found that if I run major_check_with_dataframe the 2nd time, its run time is reduced to nearly the same as running through major_check wrapper function.

```
t.set_name(name = 'major_check_with_dataframe')
t.start()
ret1 = anapyfunc.major.major_check_with_dataframe(
                                  df = df, 
                                  s_major_single_hi_percent = s_major_single_hi_percent,
                                  s_major_single_lo_percent = s_major_single_lo_percent,
                                 )
t.stop_reset()

t.set_name(name = 'major_check_with_list')
t.start()
ret2 = anapyfunc.major.major_check_with_list(
                                source_list = [a, b, c,],
                                  s_major_single_hi_percent = s_major_single_hi_percent,
                                  s_major_single_lo_percent = s_major_single_lo_percent,
                                )
t.stop_reset()


t.set_name(name = 'major_check')
t.start()
ret3 = anapyfunc.major.major_check(
                                  #source_list = [a, b, c,],
                                  df = df, 
                                  s_major_single_hi_percent = s_major_single_hi_percent,
                                  s_major_single_lo_percent = s_major_single_lo_percent,
                                 )
t.stop_reset()

t.set_name(name = 'major_check_with_dataframe')
t.start()
ret1 = anapyfunc.major.major_check_with_dataframe(
                                  df = df, 
                                  s_major_single_hi_percent = s_major_single_hi_percent,
                                  s_major_single_lo_percent = s_major_single_lo_percent,
                                 )
t.stop_reset()

t.set_name(name = 'major_check')
t.start()
ret3 = anapyfunc.major.major_check(
                                  #source_list = [a, b, c,],
                                  df = df, 
                                  s_major_single_hi_percent = s_major_single_hi_percent,
                                  s_major_single_lo_percent = s_major_single_lo_percent,
                                 )
t.stop_reset()
```

Output

```
major_check_with_dataframe elapsed time: 95.608000 ms
major_check_with_list elapsed time: 2.350000 ms
major_check elapsed time: 3.048000 ms
major_check_with_dataframe elapsed time: 2.569000 ms
major_check elapsed time: 2.520000 ms
```

Can it be some kind of memory cache effect?
This behavior is the same even if I put the functions in a class, use the class object to run the function once, and delete/garbage collect it after each run.

All functions correctly return expected values.
What am I missing here?
The version I'm using are:

Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31)

pandas 0.21.0

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for code or data related stuff.

Comment: All questions seeking debugging help must provide a [mcve]. In particular, you *must* post code in the question itself as *formatted text*, not screenshots, and *especially* not links to screen shots.

Comment: Please take some time to familiarize yourself with the guidelines at [ask].

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for the reminder. I edited my questions.